# Want to build iOS app with Right to left and left to right languages and UI according to that

Tags: ios, objective-c, localization, internationalization, right-to-left

I want to build an iOS app which deals with multiple language like english and arabic.
This language change setting will be with in my app.(Not depend on the device language). Now when user change the language from app setting,the screen UI should be updated from LTR or RTL depending on language.
I don't want to take two storyboards or restart my app.

Right now I am using Base internationalisation and using AutoLayout for designing the whole UI.(With out using Left or right constraints)
And set the selected language in NSUserDefaults.

`NSArray* language = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:MY_SELECTED_LANG, nil]; 
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:language forKey:@"AppleLanguages"];`

this code works but for that I have to restart my app. Is there any better way to do this. I am targeting device with iOS 7 and higher.

Comment: You should not have an in-app language switcher, as you will run into several other problems in the long run. You should always fall back to the system language unless you want to provide a really confusing experience for your users.

Comment: @wakachamo .Thanks, now  I am planing to not to use in-app language switcher. It will depend on device language.

Comment: @Sayakiss which post ? may i have link for it ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into NSLayoutConstraint's "trailingAnchor" and "leadingAnchor"? They are similar to "leftAnchor" and "rightAnchor" but they are not absolute and instead depend on the current language. So if you use those constraints instead of left/right, iOS should be able to help do some of the work for you, since it recognizes the difference between left- and right-reading languages, and reflects that with the leading/trailing constraint anchors.